# CSS reset is not working

Tags: html, css

CSS reset (yahooReset) is not working in cross browsers mainly between IE and chrome, why are all the div elements and fonts comparatively bigger in chrome? How can i make both browsers compatible? Appreciate any suggestions. See my code below:

```css
div#topBar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.2em auto 0em;
  height: 6em;
  background: #74756c;
}
.logo {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  /* google font*/
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 350%;
  padding: 0em 0.3em 0em;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px 8px white;
  border: 1px solid #4195fc;
}
div#box {
  margin: 0.6em 0em 1em 1em;
}
nav#navigation {
  float: right;
  font-size: 140%;
  margin: 15px 6px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="topBar">
    <div id="box">
      <b class="logo">RaGa</b>
    </div>
    <nav id="navigation">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Imprint</a>
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Privacy</a>
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Terms & Conditions</a> 
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please show where you're including your reset stylesheet and main stylesheet in the html.

Comment: reset style sheet always first to other stylesheets as I know, any way's thanks Christopher I have resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

I think some changes will help you

1. change font-size value in px
2. change em to px
3. remove `<b>` tags. This is very old.

Comment: Replace the <b> tags with <strong> as well if you want to keep the bold effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In my code I wrote below code

```
body { font-size:12px } 
/* this will create problems in cross browser rendering */
```

Google chrome got default font size of 15px which wont allow your code to render below this, but IE does.

I heard Google stopped support to below code to reset default font size.

```
* {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```